# EC2 Automatic Instance Sudo Not Working

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sudo

I'm using Atlassian Bamboo to setup a build server. It allows the use of "elastic images" which I can specify which of their AMI's to use (I'm using the Amazon Linux/CentOS image). It also allows you to add scripts for essentially "provisioning" the server. When I run the build using `sudo` in my scripts, I get errors like this:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

When not using `sudo`, I get permission denied errors.

The *script* I'm trying to run is as simple as:

```
sudo yum install -y php-mysql
sudo yum install -y php-pdo
sudo yum install -y php-pecl-xdebug
sudo yum update
```

Bamboo is setup with a key so should not require an actual password (*there isn't one as far as I know*), which means the lack of tty input should not matter, right?

If the server was spun up constantly, I could SSH into it and figure out how to enable sudo privileges, but it's not...it is created, the build is run, and then it terminates.

**TL;DR;** What can cause a dynamically spun up EBS Backed AMI to not allow `sudo`?

Comment: There is a very clear error message presented to you. Did you search here on SF or the internet in general to find out what it means ?

Comment: Yes, I understand *roughly* what it is saying. Why would it even ask for a password when Bamboo connects over SSH with a key? Additionally, the instance is spun up dynamically, how would I remove `requiretty` from the /etc/sudoers file if I can't sudo?

Comment: You need to read the error message carefully - it's nothing to do with ssh passphrases - the clue is `sudo:...`

Comment: @Iain I'm sure it as a very apparent **clue** to those who know, but I'm just not seeing the "aha moment". I'm guessing, from what I've read, I need to remove `requiretty` from the /etc/sudoers file, but if I try in my script, it will throw a **permission denied**. So...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bamboo is setup with a key so should not require an actual password (there isn't one as far as I know), which means the lack of tty input should not matter, right?*

No. This is where you're confused. How you authenticated to ssh has nothing to do with sudo. If sudo is configured to require a password, then you have to enter the user's pasword. If you don't, it won't work. If the user doesn't have a password, then it can't possibly work.

It seems you should reconfigure sudo so that

- it does not require a tty
- it does not require a password

For example, if I wanted a user named *bamboo* to be able to execute without a password any command as any user, in my */etc/sudoers* file I could have

```
bamboo  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Had to create a custom AMI with that setup already because of the whole dynamic spin up/spin down thing. Thanks for giving an actual answer and not playing a "guess the clue" game!

Answer (score 1):

[As the documentation told you](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Managing+your+elastic+image+configurations), if the images provided by Atlassian don't do that you want, then you should [create a custom image](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Creating+a+custom+elastic+image).

Answer (score -1):

check if the /etc/sudoers file is configured correctly. I had this error messages yesterday when one of our build scripts did overwrite the changes i did in the /etc/sudoers file resulting in the permission issue.